# Web3.js need only in browser version only HTML website

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, javascript

I want to create a simple page to interact with my deployed contract. I don't want to use Node.js. I want to use html + web3.js browser version. I got a link: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist

But the above link contains web3.js files that contains "require" keyword which cannot run in browser. I want browser version of web3.js.

im need testing in bsctestnet and connect

but in the moment i click Buy on my ICO html website give this error

VM338:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. Object
(anónimo) @ VM338:1
web3_request_manager.js:124 Uncaught (in promise) s: Returned error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
at f. (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@4.7.0/dist/web3.min.js:2:246727)
at Generator.next ()
at s (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@4.7.0/dist/web3.min.js:2:245237)

and i dont know what happen